# Not loading url using webview

Tags: kotlin

Am trying to run this code but it's not working. When I use 
    different 
   URL its working

```
// Initializing webview
    val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        // URL to be loaded
        webView.loadUrl("https://andela.com/alc/")
        //enabling javascript
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WebViewClient` before using it:

```
 webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

After that go with your code:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://andela.com/alc/")
```

The `WebViewClient` is from `android.webkit.WebViewClient` but you can use others too. Example: `WebChromeClient`

Comment: wvArticle.webViewClient = WebViewClient() wvArticle should be there or typing mistake

Comment: im sorry, i fixed that

Comment: If the you are satisfied with the answer please mark it as resolved so that others can profit too

Comment: Could be there another problem because is not working

Comment: 2019-07-17 14:57:01.105 5391-5429/com.example.alc4 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5